# How to Setup MvvmCross in the context of a WinRT Background Agent

Tags: windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I have a WinRT Metro style application that uses MvvmCross. The application is made up of several DLLs and many of them are taking some dependencies on MvvmCross. For example some of the DLLs use MvvmCross as an IoC container.

At this point, I would like to add to the application a WinRT background agent. The background agent will reference some of the existing DLLs that have MvvmCross dependencies. Because of this, I  need to set-up MvvmCross in the context of the background agent. Obviously, if this is even possible, the way it is done in a background agent must be different from the way it is done in a WinRT application. In the context of the WinRT application you need to create a "Setup" class inherited from MvxStoreSetup and define a constructor that takes the  root frame (Window.Current.Content) as a parameter. Obviously, in the context of the background agent there is no "root frame". Also, inheriting a class from MvxStoreSetup in the background agent code will lead to a compiler error:

Windows Runtime class ...backgroundagent.MvvmCross.Setup' has an invalid base type, 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Platform.MvxStoreSetup'.  Classes must derive either from System.Object or from a composable Windows Runtime class.  Implementation inheritance is not allowed.

Does anyone has any knowledge on how to setup MvvmCross in the context of a WinRT background agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely you'll want to setup the full MvvmCross - as that would include ViewModels and Views

> For example some of the DLLs use MvvmCross as an IoC container.

It's easy to just setup the IoC container on its own - just call `MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize()` in your service's start code.

To load plugins you'll also need to create a plugin manager and to register that with iOC using code like in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSetup.cs#L214

Putting this together, you can create your own mini-Setup if you want to - based on code from the default Store Setup class - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore/Platform/MvxStoreSetup.cs - although this would probably be overkill if all you really want is IoC